# I have a problem finalizing my code /Train a model, Evaluate result

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I what to implement the two data set and prediction
Pre-process data
Enocode columns that contains text, Normalize numberical columns, Visualize data.
Form a problem statement: Select a model, Train a model, Evaluate result.
[www.kaggle.com/alfrednieves/notebooke0d8d2a5e2/edit](https://www.kaggle.com/alfrednieves/notebooke0d8d2a5e2/edit)
https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/217299

I Need Help with the solution

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data2013=pd.read_csv('laser_incidents_2013.csv')
data2014=pd.read_csv('laser_incidents_2014.csv')
data2013.head()
data2014.head()
data2013.all
data2014.all

data2013.columns
data2014.columns

data2013=data2013.rename(columns={'DATE':'D1','Time_(UTC)':'T1','Aircraft ID':'AI1','No. A/C':'N1',
            'ALT':'A1','MAJOR CITY':'MC1', 'COLOR':'C1', 'Injury Reported':'IR1',`enter code here`'CITY':'C1', 'STATE':'S1'})

data2014=data2014.rename(columns={'DATE':'D2','Time_(UTC)':'T2','Aircraft ID':'AI2','No. A/C':'N2',
           'ALT':'A2','MAJOR CITY':'MC2', 'COLOR':'C2','Injury Reported':'IR2','CITY':'C2','STATE':'S2'})

#Lets first import the preprocessing module
from sklearn import preprocessing
#Now let's form a label Encoder model
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
#Now we use feed the label column to the model
le.fit(data2013['S1'])
le.fit(data2014['S2'])

#Model will go through column and find the unique labels (Number of classes that are there)
#Following line will print the labels found in the column
list(le.classes_)

#Following line will convert the labels to an array of numbers
le.transform(data['S1'])
#Following line will convert the labels to an array of numbers
le.transform(data['S2'])
data2013.head()
data2014.head()
#Visualize Data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plot not stressed class
plt.scatter(data['X1'], data['X2'],c=data['S1'])

plt.scatter(data['X1'][data['L']==0], data['X2'][data['L']==0],label='class1',color='blue')
plt.scatter(data['X1'][data['L']==1], data['X2'][data['L']==1],label='class2',color='red')
plt.scatter(data['X1'][data['L']==2], data['X2'][data['L']==2],label='class3',color='green')
plt.legend()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_training, X_testing, Y_training, Y_testing = train_test_split(data[['X1','X2','X3','X4']], data['L'], test_size=0.3)
plt.scatter(X_training['X1'][Y_training==0],X_training['X2'][Y_training==0],label='class1',color='blue')
plt.scatter(X_training['X1'][Y_training==1],X_training['X2'][Y_training==1],label='class2',color='red')
plt.scatter(X_training['X1'][Y_training==2],X_training['X2'][Y_training==2],label='class3',color='green')
plt.title('Training Data')
plt.legend()
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X_testing['X1'][Y_testing==0],X_testing['X2'][Y_testing==0],label='class1',color='blue')
plt.scatter(X_testing['X1'][Y_testing==1],X_testing['X2'][Y_testing==1],label='class2',color='red')
plt.scatter(X_testing['X1'][Y_testing==2],X_testing['X2'][Y_testing==2],label='class3',color='green')
plt.title('Test Data')
plt.legend()
```

MDC Classifier
Use the code that described in lectures and classify data using MDC

Then count the number of points that are missclassified in the training data and test data.

K-Nearst Neighbors Classifier
Using 5NN (5 nearest neighbors)

Then count the number of points that are missclassified in the training data and test data.

Comment: The link for the data sets: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17CTZU1WsuKjWuXybTgTla799GcobW7aN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This question seems to be open-ended. Can you tell me what exact problem you have?

Comment: The idea is to analyze the data to predict using the k-nearest neighbors algorithm. Also, graph to show the prediction. I'm trying to put two data to predict if the accident is decreasing or increasing using a green laser pointer. Thanks, Ankush

Comment: It looks the half of my code don't work.